# Image gallery without overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, slider

**The design is as follows:**

The image gallery would be like any jquery slider. There would be right and left navigation icons on that gallery. All of the galleries that i have looked into show the image and left div going left/right are hidden.

**What i use :**

Mostly I use sliderkit plugin for my jquery needs.

**What i made into the design :**

The right and left divs/images must be shown so that the gallery will go to 100%, with a white overlay png so that the image in center of the slider will be highlighted and others will seem a little dull.

If i can get an idea to work around the sliderkit plugin regarding this then it would be great or if there is any other jquery plugin that already has this functionality then i'd be more than glad to download/use it.

Comment: Take a look at this one - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/visible-nearby/